# Go: compile to static binary with PIE

Tags: go

I am looking to create a binary that can execute in an environment without a linked but also where a linker is available but PIE is required.

The closes I've gotten is where the linker states that it is statically linked but 'file' still says it is a dynamic binary.

Is there any way to get a binary that does not have an external dependency on a linker and is not a LSB shared object?

Example with go1.15.2:

```
% echo "package main;import \"fmt\";func main() {fmt.Println(\"Simple Example\")}" > main.go
% GOOS=linux go build  -ldflags "-linkmode=internal -s -w" -buildmode=pie -o mainProc main.go
% ldd mainProc
    statically linked
% file mainProc
mainProc: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, Go BuildID=8mM4GRs9zxgrVjDRg2Ch/efne9QJbJLpmKT6hRtJm/JWUYVr1m9OhJoV0v1uwq/1IZdDT8CvBOOywiI8eQq, stripped
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it:

```
go build  -ldflags '-linkmode external -s -w -extldflags "--static-pie"' -buildmode=pie -tags 'osusergo,netgo,static_build' -o /hello hello.go
```